# Vertically centering text in a Lilypond Dynamics staff

Tags: lilypond, engraving

When engraving my own scores, I like to have all dynamics centered vertically. In Lilypond, we can easily do this by inserting a `Dynamics` "staff" between the two staves of a piano score.

Whereas standard dynamic markings of *f*, *mp*, etc. are vertically centered, text dynamics are not:

[image]

```
\version "2.20.0"

right = \relative c'' {
  c1 c c c
}

left = \relative c' {
  c1 c c c
}

dynamics = {
  s1\f s-"text" s^"text" s_"text"
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff = "left" \left
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

How can I vertically center these text dynamics?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `TextScript` grobs use by default `ly:side-position-interface::y-aligned-side` for `Y-offset`, so they are treated as *side position* elements, that is, positioned either over or under the parent.

To get a different behaviour simply override `Y-offset`. If you use for example `self-alignment-interface::y-aligned-on-self` you can set the `Y-offset` to 0 with alignment determined by `self-alignment-Y`. So you can use a callback for `self-alignment-Y` to use the value of `direction` to be able to use `-"text"` for center, `^"text"` for up and `_"text"` for down.

Of course you can do other things with `Y-offset` as well, but this is what I described above:

```
\version "2.22.0"

right = \relative c'' {
  c1 c c c
}

left = \relative c' {
  c1 c c c
}

dynamics = {
  s1\f s-"text" s^"text" s_"text"
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \with {
      % Will use self-alignment-Y to place element
      \override TextScript.Y-offset = #self-alignment-interface::y-aligned-on-self
      % Use negative value of direction, i.e. CENTER -> align to center, UP -> align to bottom, DOWN -> align to top
      \override TextScript.self-alignment-Y = #(lambda (grob) (- (ly:grob-property grob 'direction)))
      % use CENTER as default direction instead of DOWN
      \override TextScript.direction = #CENTER
           
    } \dynamics
    \new Staff = "left" \left
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this with a Y-offset:

```
\version "2.20.0"

right = \relative c'' {
  c1 c c c
}

left = \relative c' {
  c1 c c c
}

dynamics = {
  \override TextScript.Y-offset = -0.5
  s1\f s^"text" 
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff = "left" \left
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```